# Cannot declare self-referencing constant

Tags: php, apache, abort

I have an error during send request to my apache server and get an Aborted response. What's the problem?

After restart apache code works well but some times stop the process and give Aborted and I must restart apache then.

> [Tue Nov 06 08:19:46 2012] [error] [client 37.63.173.114] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare self-referencing constant '(null)' in /home/sweb/project/library/Zend/File/Transfer/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 339, referer: http://sweb.net/uploader/

Comment: We need to see the code referenced in that error.

Comment: wat is the version of php? try to update the version.....earlier i had also faced the same problem with zend

Comment: @webnoob i think it's a base bug for php. many times work without any problem. http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/File/Transfer/Adapter/Abstract.php. see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45910

Comment: php 5.4.8 installed as dotdeb.org via debian

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this to be an opcode caching issue, and a bug at that.  We're seeing this and have since disabled APC.  I'm still monitoring but wasn't able to reproduce the error since disabling.

Comment: yeah i see. some version give that to me and some version didnt. dotdet repo, debian unstable and ... it's a bad bug and must be solve :(